# In what context is the MySQL keyword 'one' used?

Tags: mysql, keyword

I noticed that the word `'one'` is on the list of keywords for MySQL. I don't recall seeing any query which uses `'one'`.  I've searched on here and google, but I haven't found anything about it. Anyone have an example of when this keyword would be used?

Comment: Even though it doesn't show up in `SELECT * FROM mysql.help_keyword`. Strange

Comment: I think it's a mistake! It doesn't appear anywhere else in the manual either!

Comment: It might be a legacy from an earlier version, and it's no longer used for anything.

Comment: @Barmar Actually looking at the MySQL Reference from 4.1 the keyword `ONE` is not in there yet [https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-4.1-en.a4.pdf](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-4.1-en.a4.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it a couple places in the 5.7 Manual:

- XA Transactions for InnoDB [14.3.7.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xa-statements.html)

  `XA COMMIT xid [ONE PHASE]`
- For a `SHOW EVENTS FROM table` query ([14.7.5.18](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-events.html)), the results `Type` field can be `ONE TIME`

  ```
  mysql> SHOW EVENTS\G
  *************************** 1. row ***************************
                    Db: myschema
                  Name: e_daily
               Definer: jon@ghidora
             Time zone: SYSTEM
                  Type: ONE TIME
            Execute at: NULL
        Interval value: 10
        Interval field: SECOND
                Starts: 2006-02-09 10:41:23
                  Ends: NULL
                Status: ENABLED
            Originator: 0
  character_set_client: latin1
  collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
    Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
  ```